# Http call are not happening in this code?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

CoreService:

```
export class CoreService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
    Common.Socket.next('https://reqres.in');
  }

  httpget(url): any {
    return Common.Socket
    .switchMap((x)=> this._http.get( x + url));
  }
  httppost(url, body): any {
    return Common.Socket
    .switchMap((x)=> this._http.post( x + url, body, 
    {headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader()}
    ));
  }

  private createAuthorizationHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    return headers;
  }
}
```

component-service:

```
export class AppServiceService {

      constructor( private _coreService: CoreService) { }
      getAll(path: string){
        return this._coreService.httpget(path);
      }
     getParticular(url){
        return this._coreService.httpget(url);
      }
      create(url, body) {
        return this._coreService.httppost(url, body);
      }
    }
```

APP Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [CoreService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App-component

```
    export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
      name = 'Angular 5';
      public allPosts: any;
      constructor(private _appServiceService: AppServiceService) {
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getAllPosts();
      }
      private getAllPosts(): void {
        this._appServiceService.getAll('/api/users?page=2').subscribe(
          (res) => {
            this.allPosts = res;
            console.log(this.allPosts, 'allposts');
          }
        );
      }
      getParticular(): void {
        this._appServiceService.getParticular('/api/users/2').subscribe(
          (res) => {
            this.allPosts = res;
            console.log(this.allPosts, 'allposts');
          }
        );
      }
createMessage() {
    const url = '/api/users';
    const body = { 'name': 'morpheus-1','job': 'leader'};
    this._appServiceService.create(url, body).subscribe(
      (x) => {
        console.log(x);
      }
    );
  }
    }
```

iam calling create and getparticular from click event in app.component.html. Core service is not making http call when i making request.please give the solution for this. i think rxjs causing this issue.
i have reproduced here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcxgxv.

Answer (score 0):

It's is working when you add

```
Common.Socket.next('https://reqres.in');
```

in each function in CoreService.
Instead of using Subject for url just use string.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
export class Common {
  static Socket = "https://reqres.in";
}
```

Then add some changes in CoreService:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoreService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  httpget(url): any {
    return this._http.get( Common.Socket.toString() + url);
  }
  httppost(url, body): any {
    return this._http.post(Common.Socket.toString() + url, body,  
    {headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader()}
    );
  }

  private createAuthorizationHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    return headers;
  }
}
```

Also in AppComponent when you post message add subscription to function because Angular 4 doesn't send posts request when there is no subscription or promise on http.post

```
  createMessage() {
    const url = '/api/users';
    const body = { 'name': 'morpheus-1', 'job': 'leader' };
    this._appServiceService.create(url, body).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Actually i will make one rest call fetch endpoint. ie Before executing coreservice methods, i will make rest call to get endpoints(usually in constructor). Common.Socket.next('https://reqres.in'); -> this endpoint(https://reqres.in) is dynamic.

Comment: As per this answer, endpoint is static. i want to make it dynamic.

Comment: so you can use service which gets data of endpoints and store it, which will be injected. It could have object with endpoints data and function. When you call this function endpoints object will be filled with data. And you can just do exampleService.endpoints.allUsers. You can call function which get endpoints in exampleService constructor and endpoints data will be accesible for all your services.

Comment: i made changes in the same stackblitz. is it correct as per above comment https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcxgxv.

Comment: i tried with dynamic endpoint, where core service(derived class) method are executing before getting response from endpoint(parent class). so i am getting 404 because url is undefined.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwkvr3
In endpoint service I've implemented getter which gets endpoints. It use http when endoints are null or use existing endpoints when they are already fetched